# linux shell variable to aws command error

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, command-line

I have spent an embarrassingly long time trying to solve this riddle.

I have a shell variable called API_ID which I parsed from json using jq

```
ludo$ echo $API_ID
> "ucjj72orp1"
```

Why is it that when I copy paste it like this it works fine:

```
aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id "ucjj72orp1"
```

and like this I get an error:

```
aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id $API_ID
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the GetResources operation: Invalid REST API identifier specified 420257254224:"ucjj72orp1"
```

Comment: Did you use option `-r` in your `jq` command? If not, the variable `$API_ID` might contain double quote, that possibly makes an invalid aws id.

Comment: That worked! But how is it that when I input it manually with double quotes it works anyway?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-r` option in your `jq` command. This allows to get raw data without double quote.

If you set `myvar=$(jq '...')`, the variable will be set to a shell string including surrounding double quote.

If you copy/paste the string in an inline shell command, the shell interprets the double quote as string separator, and therefore it works.